# Efficiently displaying HTML content in a UITableViewCell

Tags: html, ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch

In the app I'm building right now, I have HTML content I want to display in a table view (a list of comments). What's the most performance-sensitive way to handle this?

Comment: The comments are formatted as HTML to allow bold text, italics, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Anything other than a `UIWebView` in each cell would be a better performing solution. For start, find any label-like control that has capability to display formatted text based on HTML-like markup. One limitation you might face is that not all HTML tags may be supported.

Looking around I found this [RTLabel](https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel). There could be few others available as well.

Hope that helps!